# Populate lookup field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have created a new custom object in Salesforce with one of the fields called Contact being a vlookup to the Contacts object. I am using SQL via the Devart Salesforce adapter to create records in the new Requests object but am not sure what to populate the Contact field with. I have tried using the ID from the record in the Contact object but that does not seem to work. Any ideas anyone ?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Did you tried to use 18- or 15-character ID ?! It's important when you work woth lookup fields, clarify please. Also add some error logs of such exists

Comment: yes I tried the Salesforce generated ID for a Contact record but the update just failed.

Comment: can you share errors which you see as result of failing? and can you show  your code with which you tried to execute upload?